# Is 70 minutes enough to connect at Frankfurt?

Tags: short-connections, lufthansa, fra, condor

In December I’m flying Manchester>Frankfurt>Holguin on a single ticket (Lufthansa connecting to Condor, booked direct with Condor). My inbound flight is scheduled to arrive in FRA at 08:50, the onward Condor flight departs at 10:00. My bag will be checked through to Holguin but I will have hand luggage.

I’ve done this route several times before, but never on a weekday morning or with such a short connection.

- is it really feasible to deplane, clear security and get to the gate before it closes?
- Condor only flies twice-weekly to Holguin, the next flight is not until 4 days later. It’s also the only European airline flying into Holguin. What happens if I don’t make it to the gate in time, or miss my connection because the MAN>FRA flight arrives late? What happens if the next flight(s) are full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* your incoming flight is on time, you'll be fine.  Both Manchester and Holguin are in the non-Schengen area so you don't need to go through immigration, just clear transit security and walk to your next gate.

If your incoming flight is delayed/cancelled and you miss the connection, though, you're likely facing significant delays at best.  Condor is LCC-ish and unlikely to want to endorse you onto another carrier.  In your shoes I'd probably investigate alternatives and see if they can eg. fly you to Havana instead (Condor flies this too twice a week, but on different days) and you can take a connecting domestic flight.  Worse case scenario, they refund your money and you'll need to find your own way to Cuba.

Comment: If you have not yet bought your tickets, how about an earlier UK to Frankfurt flight? Possibly even staying overnight in Frankfurt.

Comment: Coming from Manchester you may not have to clear security. Depends on where your plane docks though.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don’t think there are any connecting domestic flights from Havana to Holguin. Flying to Havana would mean a 15 hour bus journey to my final destination of Santiago de Cuba

Comment: @Traveller Wikipedia indicates that Aerogaviota flies between the two.  You would likely need to arrange the ticket on your own though.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thanks. After seeing your answer I’ve re-booked my ticket, it cost me €150 admin but gives me a 2 hour 10 min layover, which has always been adequate on this route so far. TBH if I had to go via Havana I’d probably not make the trip at all, nowadays in Cuba there are too many risks around safety and unreliable scheduling for my liking as a solo traveller.